# Cannot kill a windows process in cygwin

Tags: windows, cygwin, kill, xargs

I can kill a windows process in Cygwin with the command:

```
$ echo "4128" | xargs kill -f
```

but cannot do it with the following command:

```
$ kill -f 4128
-bash: kill: f: invalid signal specification
```

According to documentation of `kill` the syntax should be correct https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/kill.html

You can find there:

```
$ kill -f 123
```

Why doesn't the second command work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cygwin has 2 kills:

```
$ type -a kill
kill is a shell builtin
kill is /usr/bin/kill
```

The shell builtin does not support the -f option. You need to use the kill
executable:

```
/bin/kill -f
```

Or:

```
env kill -f
```

Comment: Yes. It works. But it doesn't explain (at least me) why the first command works without /bin/kill

Comment: @ka3ak the first command works because you cannot pipe to a builtin, so the executable is automatically used